# issue to send authorization token in header in ionic 3 angular 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, http-headers, ionic3, angular5

Can you provide a demo to send authorization token in request header and get that token in php file?

I am using get method for request but it will call OPTIONS method.

Here is My code:

```
getData()
{
    let hdrs = new HttpHeaders();
    hdrs.set('Authorization',"token");
    return this.http.get(apiUrl,{ headers : hdrs});
}
```

Comment: Try that `let hdrs = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization',"token");` The OPTIONS method is because of CORS

Comment: Also, in my php code I add this line to my API call inside the function :                             header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true "); header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods:*"); header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
getData()
{
    let hdrs = new HttpHeaders();
    hdrs = hdrs.set('Authorization',"token"); // assign back to hdrs
    return this.http.get(apiUrl,{ headers : hdrs});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This** :-

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
changeStatusDeactive(params) {
    const localStorageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.userData);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': localStorageData.token
    });
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.apiUrl + '/rest/agency/deactive', params, {
        headers: headers
    });
}
```

And If Only OPTIONS method called than you need to allow Authorization from Backend else it will give error of access-control-allow-origin